# R ggplot dual X axis, one linear and one log, but for different variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot the sample dataset shown below like so: Y axis - Var2 (linear scale); X_bottom_axis - Var1 (linear scale); X_top_axis - Var3 (log scale)

The problem is that all my top X-axis is cramming together all the ticks and doesn't function as log scale. The picture exemplifies the format I want to achieve for my plot. Any ideas?
[image: Desirable format]

Below code shows a sample dataset and my unsuccessful attempt to plot it

```
d1 <- data.frame(var1=c(1,2,3,4,5),var2=c(100,110,99,94,100),var3=c(1e-6,12e-6,27e-6,1e-5,1e-3))
ggplot(d1,aes(y=var2))+geom_point(aes(x=var1),col="blue")+geom_point(aes(x=var3),col="red")+scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~., breaks = c(1e-6,1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,1e-1,0)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a secondary axis *doesn't change where the red dots are plotted*. You need to apply a transformation to the data so that they are approximately on the same scale as the blue dots. For example. taking `log10` of `var3` and adding 6 will change the red dots to be between the values of 1 and 3 so they are clearly visible on the plot. All the secondary axis does is to provide an annotation showing how these red dots should be interpreted. To do this, you need to pass a function that inverts this transformation (i.e. `~10^(.x - 6)`

```r
ggplot(d1, aes(y = var2)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = var1), col = "blue") +
  geom_point(aes(x = log10(var3) + 6), col = "red")+
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~10^(.x - 6), breaks = 10^(-6:0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Allan! I now understand the concept of transformation of second X axis with respect to first X axis.